# Why does TFS Build Get Sources return error 255?

Tags: tfs

After restarting my service, I am getting an error when trying to build:

```
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5149190Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Get Sources'
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5149190Z ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5149190Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5149190Z ##[debug]=> (Boolean) True
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5149190Z ##[debug]Expanded: True
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5149190Z ##[debug]Result: True
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5305444Z ##[section]Starting: Get Sources
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5305444Z ##[debug]Sync source for endpoint: Cashware
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5930456Z Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'tf.exe'.
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5930456Z ##[debug]Path: 'c:\agent\externals\vstsom;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\TFSAgent\.dotnet\tools;c:\agent\bin;c:\agent\bin'
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5930456Z Setting environment variable TFVC_BUILDAGENT_POLICYPATH
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5930456Z Querying workspace information.
2021-04-10T13:17:40.5930456Z ##[debug]tf vc workspaces /format:xml /collection:http://srvtfs1:8080/tfs/XXXXX/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt
2021-04-10T13:17:41.5618135Z ##[error]Exit code 255 returned from process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc workspaces /format:xml /collection:http://srvtfs1:8080/tfs/XXXXX/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt'.
2021-04-10T13:17:41.5774396Z ##[debug]Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessExitCodeException: Exit code 255 returned from process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc workspaces /format:xml /collection:http://srvtfs1:8080/tfs/XXXXX/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt'.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.TfsVCCommandManager.<RunPorcelainCommandAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

Comment: Hi @Pabbo, Could you try to install another self-hosted agent and try it again? According to the error message, it seems that the agent folder structure is corrupted

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?